# How to split the array values and store in a string in android?

Tags: android

I am getting the values from arraylist **arr** and storing those values in a string with comma separator. But for the last value also comma is adding. How can I remove that? Please help me...

My Code:

```
ArrayList<String> arr;  
String str;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

                int kk = arr.size();
                System.out.println("splitting test" + arr.get(i));
                str += arr.get(i) + ",";

                System.out.println("result" + str);


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add it at all:

```
ArrayList<String> arr;  
String str;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
   int kk = arr.size();
   System.out.println("splitting test" + arr.get(i));
   str += arr.get(i);
   if (i + 1 != arr.size()) {
     str+= ",";
   }
   System.out.println("result" + str);
}
```

Comment: hi thank you..its working fine..Also another string data is like a,b,c,|,d,e,f,|,g,h,k,|  Now I want to split the string first with "|" and then the result with ",". How can I do that? Please help me

Comment: Hi thank you for the link...It helped me...Also in my string a,b,c,|,d,e,f,|,g,h,k,|.....I want to remove comma after the | symbol. Please help me how to remove that.Thank you

Comment: you will cope with your problem if you simply first split on ",\\|," instead of splitting only on '|'. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(Object item : arrayOrIterable) builder.append(item).append(",");
String result = builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try this, I think is should work.

```
ArrayList<String> arr;  
String str;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

                int kk = arr.size();
                System.out.println("splitting test" + arr.get(i));
                str += arr.get(i) + i!=arr.size()-1?"":",";

                System.out.println("result" + str);


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always write like this.

```
String str;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

            int kk = arr.size();
            System.out.println("splitting test" + arr.get(i));
            // It is your old code str += arr.get(i) + ",";
            // Insted write like this

            str += arr.get(i);
            if (i < arr.size() - 1) {
                str += ",";
            }
            System.out.println("result" + str);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

add one condition in for loop

```
if(i == arr.size()-1)
{
    str += arr.get(i);
}
else
{
   str += arr.get(i) + ",";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass array list to this function. it will return comma separated values.

```
public static <T> String getReasonArray(Collection<T> values) {
    if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) return "";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (T val : values) {
        result.append(val);
        result.append(",");
    }
    return result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell how / why this works and what OP was doing wrong?